# Proposition 4.19 in Brezis's Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces, convolution

I'm trying to prove **Proposition 4.19.** in Brezis's *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f \in \mathcal C_c (\mathbb R^n)$ and $g \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. Then $(f*g) (x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $(f * g) \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R^n)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Let $S$ be the compact support of $f$.

1. Fix $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Then
   $$
   \begin{align}
   (f*g) (x) &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y) g(y) \ \mathrm d y \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y) g(y)  1_{x-S} (y) \ \mathrm d y.
   \end{align}
   $$

We have $f(x-\cdot)$ belongs to $L^{\infty} (\mathbb R^n)$, and $g 1_{x-S}$ belongs to $L^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. By Hölder's inequality, $f(x-\cdot) g 1_{x-S}$ belongs to $L^1$. Hence $(f*g) (x)$ is well-defined.

2. Let $x, x_n \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $x_n \to x$. Let $K$ be the closure of $\{x, x_1, \ldots, x_n, \ldots\}$. Then $K$ is compact. Notice that
   $$
   \begin{align}
   (f*g) (x_n) &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x_n-y)   g(y) 1_{K-S} (y), \\
   (f*g) (x) &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y) g(y) 1_{K-S} (y).
   \end{align}
   $$

Because $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n-y) g(y) 1_{K-S} (y) \to f(x-y) g(y) 1_{K-S} (y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^n$. On the other hand,
$$
|f(x_n-y) g(y) 1_{K-S} (y)| \le \|f\|_{\infty} |g(y)| 1_{K-S} (y)|
\quad \forall n, \forall y \in \mathbb R^n.
$$

It follows from $K-S$ is compact that $g 1_{K-S}$ is integrable. The claim then follows from dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is correct, although the second part could be done  simpler.

Let $K={\rm supp}\,f.$ The function $f$ is uniformly continuous. Hence for $\varepsilon>0$ there is $1\ge\delta>$ such that $$\|u-v\|\le \delta \implies |f(u)-f(v)|<\varepsilon $$ Fix $x$ and let $U_\delta=\{x'\, :\,\|x'-x\|\le \delta\}.$
Then for $x'\in U_\delta$ we obtain $$|(f*g)(x)-(f*g)(x')| \\ \le \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x-s)-f(x'-s)|\,|g(s)|\,ds\\ \le \varepsilon\int\limits_{U_\delta-K}|g(s)|\,ds \le \varepsilon\int\limits_{U_1-K}|g(s)|\,ds$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification!