# Proposition 4.20 in Brezis's Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convolution

If $f \in \mathcal C^k (\mathbb R^n)$ and $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ is a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation?useskin=vector#Definition_and_basic_properties) of length $|\alpha | = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n \le k$, then we write
$$
D^\alpha f := D_1^{\alpha_1} D_2^{\alpha_2} \ldots D_n^{\alpha_n}  f 
\quad \text{where} \quad
D_i^{\alpha_i} := \frac{\partial^{\alpha_i}}{\partial x_i^{\alpha_i}}.
$$

I'm trying to prove **Proposition 4.20.** in Brezis's *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $k \ge 1,f \in \mathcal C^k_c (\mathbb R^n)$, and $g \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. Then $(f*g) (x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Also, $(f * g) \in \mathcal C^k (\mathbb R^n)$ and
> $$
> D^\alpha (f*g) = (D^\alpha f) *g
> \quad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb N^n \text{ s.t. } |\alpha| \le k.
> $$
> In particular, if $f \in \mathcal C^\infty_c (\mathbb R^n)$ and $g \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\mathbb R^n)$, then $(f*g) \in \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** We need the following lemma, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665223/proposition-4-19-in-breziss-functional-analysis) Let $f \in \mathcal C_c (\mathbb R^n)$ and $g \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. Then $(f*g) (x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $(f * g) \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R^n)$.

By above **Lemma**, $(f*g) (x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

First we prove for the case $k=1$. Fix $x \in \mathbb R^n$, we claim that $f*g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $\nabla (f*g) (x) = (\nabla f )*g (x)$. Let $h \in \mathbb R^n$ with $|h|<1$. By mean value theorem (in integral form), for all $y \in \mathbb R^n$,
$$
\begin{align}
& |f(x-y+h)-f(x-y) - h \cdot \nabla f (x-y)| \\
= & \bigg | \int_0^1 h \cdot (\nabla f(x-y + sh) -  \nabla f (x-y)) \ \mathrm d s  \bigg| \\
\le & |h| \varepsilon (|h|)
\end{align}
$$
with $\varepsilon (|h|) \to 0$ as $|h| \to 0$ (since $\nabla f$ is uniformly continuous).

Let $K := \operatorname{supp} f$. Then $\operatorname{supp} (\nabla f) \subset K$. Let $K'$ be a compact set that contains $x+ B(0, 1)-K$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
& \bigg |\frac{(f*g) (x+h) - (f*g) (x)  - h \cdot ((\nabla f )*g (x))}{h} \bigg | \\
= & \frac{1}{h}\bigg | \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x+h-y) g(y)  \ \mathrm d y - \int_{\mathbb R^n}  f(x-y) g(y) \ \mathrm d y - h \cdot \int_{\mathbb R^n}  \nabla f(x-y) g(y) \ \mathrm d y \bigg | \\
= & \frac{1}{h}\bigg | \int_{\mathbb R^n} [ f(x+h-y)  -  f(x-y) - h \cdot \nabla f(x-y)  ] g(y)  \ \mathrm d y  \bigg | \\
\le &\varepsilon (|h|) \int_{\mathbb R^n} g(y) 1_{K'} (y) \ \mathrm d y.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(y) 1_{K'} (y) \ \mathrm d y$ is finite because $g \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. The claim follows by taking limit $h \to 0$. It follows from $f \in \mathcal C^1_c (\mathbb R^n)$ that $\nabla f \in \mathcal C_c (\mathbb R^n)$. Then $(\nabla f )*g \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R^n)$ by **Lemma**. Because $\nabla (f*g) = (\nabla f )*g$, we get $\nabla (f*g) \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R^n)$ and thus $f*g \in \mathcal C^1 (\mathbb R^n)$.

Now we prove for general $k \ge 1$ by induction. Assume the statement holds for $k$. We will prove that it holds for $k+1$. Let $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ be a multi-index such that $|\alpha| = k+1$. WLOG, we assume $\alpha_1 \ge 1$. Let $\beta = (\alpha_1-1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$. Then $|\beta| =k$. By inductive hypothesis,

- $(f * g) \in \mathcal C^k (\mathbb R^n)$, and
- $$
  D^\beta (f*g) = (D^\beta f) *g.
  $$

Clearly, $D^\beta f \in \mathcal C^1_c (\mathbb R^n)$. The base case $k=1$ implies

- $(D^\beta f) *g \in \mathcal C^1 (\mathbb R^n)$ and thus $D^\beta (f*g) \in \mathcal C^1 (\mathbb R^n)$.
- $$
  D_1^1 ((D^\beta f) *g) = (D_1^1  D^\beta f ) *g  = (D^\alpha f) * g.
  $$

Hence

- $(f*g) \in \mathcal C^{k+1} (\mathbb R^n)$, and
- $$
  D^\alpha (f*g) = D_1^1 D^\beta (f*g) \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R^n).
  $$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof look's fine to me, alternatively you could also have started from the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: @blamethelag Thank you so much for your verification!